# GraphQL cannot determine output type for JSON

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am getting a graphQL error

*Cannot determine GraphQL output type for 'myTestField'. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper output value?*

The type and field looks like this

```
@ObjectType
export class TestApp {
:
:

@Field(() => JSON)
myTestField: JSON;
:
:
}
```

I know the solution that if JSON were a type then I can simply decorate it with @ObjectType but in this case this is a generic JSON object